# C# Seeding StaticRandom in parallel.for to get a reproducible sequence

Tags: c#, multithreading, random, seed

I'm working on a C# project that requires random numbers in a parallel.for loop. For this purpose I am using the StaticRandom class from Jon Skeet's MiscUtil.

For testing I want to be able to reproduce my results. Therefore I have tried to seed the underlying System.Random to get the same sequence each time the test runs. However, even with the seed i get a different result each time. In a regular for loop the same sequence is outputtet each time. There is code to reproduce my problem below (you will have to update the expected sequence with the output from your machine).

Is there a way to seed the Random so I can get a reproducible sequence in the parallel.for loop?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MultiThreadedSeededRandom()
    {
        var actual = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
        Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
        {
            actual.Add(StaticRandom.Next(1000));
        });

        WriteActualToOutput(actual);

        var expected = new int[] { 743, 51, 847, 682, 368, 959, 245, 849, 192, 440, };

        Assert.IsTrue(AreEqual(expected, actual.ToArray()));
    }

    public static bool AreEqual<T>(T[] expected, T[] actual)
    {
        if (expected.Length != actual.Length)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < expected.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!expected[i].Equals(actual[i]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void WriteActualToOutput(ConcurrentBag<int> acual)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        result += "new int[] {";
        foreach (var value in acual)
        {
            result += value.ToString() + ",";
        }
        result += "};";

        Trace.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public static class StaticRandom
    {
        private static Random random = new Random(1231241);
        private static object myLock = new object();

        public static int Next(int max)
        {
            object obj;
            Monitor.Enter(obj = StaticRandom.myLock);
            int result;
            try
            {
                result = StaticRandom.random.Next(max);
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(obj);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if you took all the random samples at application startup time and stored them for use later. Then it wouldn't matter what order the sampling threads used them.

Comment: Also, maybe do all the sampling itself in a specific thread unsing an Invoke?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `Parallel.For`, by design, you're going to get results out of sequence, since each iteration will run in parallel in a non-deterministic manner.  If you need to have the same sequence of "random" numbers, you'll need to call `Random.Next()` in a reliable order.  This will not work from multiple threads.

Instead of trying to use `Parallel.For` to populate the random numbers, you should consider generating the sequence of "random" numbers in advance, then use `Parallel.For` to do the processing based on these numbers after the fact.  This way, you'll always generate the numbers in the proper order, which will preserve the sequencing.

Comment: Ahh yes. I assumed they were completely different sequences but it is actually only the order that is different. I will try to generate the random numbers before the actual parallel.For. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On a separate note you could use the efficiencies of StringBuilder in your Output method if you have never used it:

```
private static void WriteToArrayString(ICollection items)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder("new []{");

        var index = 0;
        foreach(var value in items)
        {
            if (index == (items.Count - 1))
            {
                result.Append(string.Concat(value));
                index++;
                continue;
            }
            result.Append(string.Concat(value, ','));
            index++;
        }
        result.Append("};");

        Trace.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
```